# Add TemplateMethod's through XML

Tags: java, xml, freemarker

I want to add TemplateMethods from a XML File to Freemarker, without touching existing every time.
This is already possible with values like this:

**Example XML:**

```
<example>
    <value1>abc</value>
    <value2>def</value>
</example>
```

**Example Template:**

```
This value1: ${doc.example.value1} and this value2: ${doc.example.value2}
```

*I can add as much values as i want into the xml and use it in the template without changes in the calling program.*

---

How can i do this with implementations of `TemplateMethodModel`, without chaning my Freemarker code everytime i add / remove one?

More specific - what i want to do:

**XML Model:**
*containing the class and the name of the TemplateMethod*

```
<templatemethodmodel>
   <method name="intToHex">example.methods.IntToHexMethod</method>
</templatemethodmodel>
```

**Template:**
*calling an instance of `IntToHexMethod`'s class*

```
Only an example: ${intToHex(3)}
```

Now it should be possible to add new methods (= xml entry with name and a class) without touching my java code where i process the templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it through the DOM-wrapper of FreeMarker (i.e. through exposing a DOM object as "doc"), then you can't do this (unless you extend `freemarker.ext.dom.NodeModel`, but that's probably difficult). But if you don't really need the DOM-wrapper with all the XML-related features (like XPath), you could just make a `Map` (of `Map`-s of `Map`-s etc.) from the XML and expose the `Map` as `doc` for the templates. (Or, you could write your own `DOM` Node wrapper that exposes the XML to the templates exactly as you want it, but that's somewhat more involved.)

Comment: I actually don't need features like xpath, it's fully enough if i can add new Methods (through the classname in the xml) to freemarker. Freemarker should then put an instance of each class (named in xml) to the model so i can use it in the template.

Comment: So then, as I said, FreeMarker will not magically just do exactly that. But you could build the required structure from `Map`-s. (Or if you need a really cute and efficient solution, you could implement this as an `ObjectWrapper` of `org.w3c.dom.Node`, but that requires some FreeMarker-specific knowledge.)

Comment: Thanks! Used two maps: one for the XML part (containing more maps + names), and another one which contains name-instance pairs (with instances of the class). This one is added to freemarker. Now i can add / remove methods to / from xml without touching the freemarker code.